# How can I display a tile on my TFS project home page with the remaining effort across all user stories?

Tags: tfs

How can I display a tile on my TFS project home page with the remaining effort across all user stories?

We're using the Scrum template in TFS 2012.

It's easy to write a query for the number of Product Backlog Items, or the number of Tasks, but I'd really like a metric showing the remaining effort for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in the TFS WA.

You could alternatively create an Excel report and integrate it in the SharePoint dashboard.